# sql developer time format

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to add a column into my DB oracle SQL DEVELOPER.
This column needs the format `HH:MI:SS`, but when I set the column as timestamp,
it convert me the column as : `DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS`, even if I change `NLS Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the preferences as follows:

Go to `Tools > Preferences`.

In `Preferences` dialog, select `Database > NLS` from the left panel.

From the list of `NLS parameters`, enter `HH:MI:SS` into the `Timestamp Format` field.

Save and close the dialog.

Comment: My solution is more of a general approach on how to format a date into a String

Answer (score 1):

The actual value saved in the db in not even that. What is saved in the database is a number that represents the date. What you actually see is how the SQL Developer represents that date, and not how it is actually stored.

You can print the date in the format you want using `to_char()` :

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') as "Current Time" from dual;
```